# how to generate random unix timestamps mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to generate random unix timestamps and only found this example:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(
       unix_timestamp('2008-01-01 01:00:00')+floor(rand()*31536000)
);
```

This works for generating a random time, but it reconverts the time into this format `2008-06-16 14:14:38` which is *not* the format I want. I want the result to be a unix time stamp, for example `1357597694` in UTC-5.

All I want to do is be able to tell it how many unix timestamps to spit out and have the result be in unixtime stamp form. That's all. I don't see why there isn't a post about this already.

*EDITED*
ok salman A

ok lets say i need to pick a random date between 1354439504 & 1357599297 how would i do that in mysql script

Comment: So remove the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` which converts the time stamp into a string?

Comment: You might want to bookmark [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) .. as it would have explained your result ;-)

Answer (score 7):

1 is a UNIX timestamp. So is 2. So is 123456789. [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is just an integer; and the rules for generating random integers can be used. In MySQL you could simply write the following to generate a random integer in the range `[0, 9]`:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 10)
```

The above can be modified to generate random numbers in the range `[min, max]` as follows:

```
SELECT 1354439504 + FLOOR(RAND() * (1357599297 - 1354439504 + 1))
```

To generate 1000 random timestamps using a query, use a table, any table, that has many rows:

```
SELECT 1354439504 + FLOOR(RAND() * (1357599297 - 1354439504 + 1))
FROM table_with_1000plus_rows
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: ok lets say i need to pick a random date between 1354439504 & 1357599297 how would i do that then mysql script

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted a unix timestamp, then just skip the `from_unixtime`:

```
select unix_timestamp('2008-01-01 01:00:00')+floor(rand()*31536000)
```

Comment: omg eric thanks i want to send you a moneygram payment for your help this has been frustrating...now one more thing how to i tell to make 50 or 10 at a time for example